# I got this error in android studio Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException:

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I have got this `Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException:` while importing Eclipse project into android studio.

Comment: i am using android studio

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace please ?

Answer (score 0):

If Path contains non-ASCII characters then correct it.
Clear the build cache. 
Look this reference for details.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache.html

If it not solve the problem Move project further up your project file path and try!